# Anti capture screen in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a program to stop the recording the screen, and I used the following code to do that.

```
 const uint WDA_NONE = 0;
    const uint WDA_MONITOR = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hWnd, uint dwAffinity);
    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this.Handle, WDA_MONITOR);
    }
```

However, this code does not work for Merlis Action software.

Comment: You are playing a game of walls and ladders. Clearly "Merlis Action software" has a longer ladder then then wall you can make: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253 | Do not play games of walls and ladders, nobody will win but the user will loose.

Comment: And at the end of all this, someone will just whip out their cellphone and point its camera at their monitor...

Comment: you can't _prevent_ screen capture. you can only make it harder. but at some point, there's the hardware capture device. so save yourself the trouble and time. the main point about computers people seem to keep forgetting: whatever you can _view_, you can _copy_.

Comment: We just embed ids in what we show people and don't tell them "if we find this floating round the internet with your id on it, we'll sue you"

Answer (score -2):

As you can see in the code above, the program was running and the screen recording programs were doing their job.
However, the form in which the relevant code is executed is displayed in black and white in the recorded video, but Merlis َAction software avoids this.